# Programmers.SE and Data Explorer

Tags: discussion

Now that we're out of Beta, when will Programmers show up in the Data Explorer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the next monthly data dump *.

The data explorer runs on a copy of the Stack Exchange data which is refreshed around the end of each month.

* Assuming that it's not affected by Christmas/New Year.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.